# ServiceStack Redis Auth Persistence

Tags: authentication, redis, persistence, servicestack

I'm attempting to learn how to use Redis for UserAuth persistence in ServiceStack.

I have the following code inside my Global.asax.cs:

```cs
public class HelloAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public HelloAppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CredentialsAuthProvider()
        }));
        container.Register(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(
            "127.0.0.1:6379"
        ));
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(
            c => new RedisAuthRepository(c.Resolve<PooledRedisClientManager>()));
    }
}
```

I have a default install/config of Redis exposed locally on TCP/6379 (from the Deb7 package).

When I call the auth service I receive the following error:

```cs
Response Status

Error Code RedisResponseException
MessageZero length respose, sPort: 65470, LastCommand: 
Stack Trace[Auth: 07/06/2013 17:29:08]: [REQUEST: {UserName:test,Password:test}]
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: Zero length respose, sPort: 65470, LastCommand: at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.CreateResponseError(String error) at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ParseSingleLine(String r) at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ReadData() at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectData(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs) at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.HGet(String hashId, Byte[] key) at 
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.GetValueFromHash(String hashId, String key) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.RedisClientManagerFacade.RedisClientFacade.GetValueFromHash(String hashId, String key) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.RedisAuthRepository.GetUserAuthByUserName(IRedisClientFacade redis, String userNameOrEmail) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.RedisAuthRepository.GetUserAuthByUserName(String userNameOrEmail) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.RedisAuthRepository.TryAuthenticate(String userName, String password, UserAuth& userAuth) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.CredentialsAuthProvider.TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, String userName, String password) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.CredentialsAuthProvider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, String userName, String password, String referrerUrl) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.CredentialsAuthProvider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Authenticate(Auth request, String provider, IAuthSession session, IAuthProvider oAuthConfig) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Post(Auth request) at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Get(Auth request) at 
lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ) at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, Object instance, TRequest request)
```

What is causing this error?

I suspect it may be one of the following:

-Do I need to setup Redis somehow?
-Is there a mistake inside my Global.asax.cs?
-Is there something else missing?
-Am I completely on the wrong track?!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you hit your redis box connecting from the box that's trying to authenticate? Try just doing `redis-cli -h [box_host_name]` -p 6379. Does it get you in? If so, try setting and getting some keys and verifying this works.

Comment: Ok, so my Redis server is running on a guest deb7 VM, with host TCP/6379 forwarded to guest TCP/6379. redis-cli work as expected from the guest but on the host using the win7x64 redis-cli the server closes the connection upon issuing any command:

Comment: Error: Server closed the connection

Comment: Could this be a version mismatch? server: 2.4.14 cli: 2.6.12 or is there a network level problem with the port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else has this problem, it looks like this was due to a version mismatch between the client and server (the debian 7 stable package is from the old 2.4.x branch). I built the server from 2.6.13 source and all seems ok.